# aiogram 3 нужно сформировать ссылку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

Сделал ответ бота с картинками товаров, т.е.
await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=msg.from_user.id, media=[...])
Появляются 9 картинок.
При нажатии на картинку внизу идет описание(caption). в последней строке хочу сделать ссылку на этот товар. Нажимая на эту ссылку бот присылает новое сообщение, с более детальным описанием товара и фотографиями с разных ракурсов и инлайт кнопкой "Оплатить".
Как сформировать ссылку?

Comment: На какую ссылку? Как отловить? Поясните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос.

Comment: ловите сетью...если будете ловить на удочку, то дольше ждать придется. Так как мы понятия не имеем о какой ссылке идет речь, то вот вам точно [полезная ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сделать именно то, что нужно - не знаю. Могу предложить использовать команды по типу /img1, /img2 и тд. А в caption соответственно их добавить. При нажатии бот будет выполнять команду в соответствии с изображением.

Comment: да, это простое решение! я про него не знал... спасибо